# nodes in linked list with smart or raw pointers?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I know that this question is more a less subjective to what you are doing, but is there a general rule of thumb about the use of raw pointers versus smart pointers in a node class?

More specifically, if I were to have a linked list where the node can have infinite children, but only one parent, would it be better to use smart or raw pointers?

Comment: Wouldn't that require all instances of pointers to nodes to be smart pointers, including each nodes pointer to the next (and previous) node(s)? Seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: so... I should use raw for simplicity. cuz If i do lose part of the chain it will be leaked memory. Cuz they will always be pointed at by some part of the list

Comment: It depends on how linked lists are created. If there is a maximum number of nodes for all lists to be used by a program, a single allocation of an array of nodes could be done. The array of nodes could then be linked together to form a single "free pool" list of nodes to be used for node allocation and node deallocation. When the program completes, the state of the lists would not matter, as the program would just free that original array of nodes.

Comment: Think about it this way: Who owns a node? Node A doesn't own the next node in the list, the linked list does, so Node A should not be responsible for the deletion of the next node. It doesn't know enough about the list to be making those sorts of decisions. Only the list does.

Comment: Sounds like a *tree*. But it depends on your precise use. My first guess would be `std::unique_ptr` for the children and *raw pointer* for the parent. But need more info.

Comment: I know this isn't what's asked, but you should ALWAYS think about "why am I re-engineering a standard container rather than just using them?"  If you can answer this question well, then fine.  But if not, you shouldn't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it depends which kind of Linked list you are talking about

if it is double linked list 
unique pointer forward  with a raw pointer backward works

shared pointer works but its too much  (it will be using sword to cut vegetable)

Excellent video  **CppCon 2016: Herb Sutter “Leak-Freedom in C++**

https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE?t=23m6s